# Automatically gather all quickChecks

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Being a fan of quickCheck, I have a lot of

```
prop_something_something = ...
```

throughout my program.

For convenience, to easily run all of them, I define

```
runchecks = do
    quickCheck prop_something_something
    quickCheck prop_something_different
```

but is there a nice way to generate `runchecks`?

TL;DR: I want to easily run all quickChecks in a file. I guess one way is to prefix the runnable tests with test_ or something similar, but that might be too hacky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the [`test-framework-th`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework-th) package. Just do:

```
import Test.Framework.TH
import Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2
runchecks = $(defaultMainGenerator)
```

This will use the `test-framework` way of running tests, i.e. you'll get slightly more information than what you'd get by simply running the tests one after the other, which oftentimes is a good thing.

You obviously need `TemplateHaskell` to be enabled for this to work; either add `Default-extensions: TemplateHaskell` to your Cabal file, or add `{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}` to the top of the file.

Comment: By just adding that, I get this error: http://hpaste.org/67672 - do I have to make other changes? I'll paste more code if you want to.

Comment: Apparently, you have to include the `QuickCheck2` provider module as well, which makes sense I guess. See my updated answer for more info.

Comment: Yes, adding  import Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2 worked. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 8):

An extra note: this functionality exists out of the box in QuickCheck 2 as well, see the function [`quickCheckAll`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-All.html#v:quickCheckAll), which requires an import of `Test.QuickCheck.All` as well as `TemplateHaskell`. `quickCheckAll` will test all functions in your module whose name starts with `prop_`.